# JQuery show/hide issue using Select (Dropdown) on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I'm struggling with this issue and searched all over for an answer that works. The problem only applies to IOS Devices as far as I could test.

I have a select (dropdown) element with options. When the user selects an option, the div corresponding to that option displays. The script shows and hides the divs as needed.

The problem comes in when using Safari on IOS 10. The spin wheel shows the options, but when selecting an option and clicking done, nothing happens.

Onclick event doesn't fire or something.

Works fine on Desktop browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('.hidebox').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).prop("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).show(200);
    } else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidebox {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selection">
  <select class="form-control">
      <option onclick="showonlyone('newboxes1');">Option 1</option>
      <option onclick="showonlyone('newboxes2');">Option 2</option>
      <option onclick="showonlyone('newboxes3');">Option 3</option>
      <option onclick="showonlyone('newboxes4');">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="container" style="margin-top:20px">
  <div class="hidebox showbox" id="newboxes1">Selected 1</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes2">Selected 2</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes3">Selected 3</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes4">Selected 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>function showonlyone(thechosenone) {

  $('.hidebox').each(function(index) {

    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).show(200);
    } else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  });
}</script>
```

Use attr for getting attribute values.

```
<div id="selection">
  <select class="form-control" onchange="showonlyone(this.value)">
      <option value="newboxes1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="newboxes2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="newboxes3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="newboxes4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="container" style="margin-top:20px">
  <div class="hidebox showbox" id="newboxes1">Selected 1</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes2">Selected 2</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes3">Selected 3</div>
  <div class="hidebox" id="newboxes4">Selected 4</div>
</div>
```

use onchange in select tag rather than using click for options.

Answer (score 0):

Try using other function. [example here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-jquery.php)

Comment: This solution also worked with a little bit of modification. Thank you so much for your time..